# Error : React Native Failed to load bundle

Tags: reactjs, macos, react-native, react-router, reactive-programming

I am getting this error in ios emulator.
Error :

> failed to load bundle. platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false error
>   :(could not connect to devalopment server)

Comment: can you please tell us more about technical issue with your tried code and errors you got.

Comment: This usually means your metro packager isnt running properly. Can you please make sure your packager is running? And how did you setup your project? Is it running expo? React native init?

Comment: i just followed the steps in this link " https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html  ". finally when i run react-native run-ios command ,iphone emulator is opening and getting the above error on emulator with red colour background.